# Spring Data, MySQL, connection dies after 8 hours of inactivity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am facing an issue where my datasource bean is going down after a period of inactivity. My question is how could I re instantiate the datasource bean that gets hit on application startup.

Here is how we setup the bean on startup.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    byte[] encryptedFile = fileRetriever.getFile(bucket, key);
    String unencryptedJson = fileDecrypter.decryptFile(encryptedFile);
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try{
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(unencryptedJson);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
    }

    String password = (String)jsonObject.get("password");

    DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .url(url)
            .username(userName)
            .password(password)
            .build();

    return ds;

}
```

This class also has a `@Configuration` annotation on it.

We have other applications that do not have this issue where the service needs to be bounced after inactivity, but they are also not setting up the data source in this manner and have all the details specified in the `application.property` file

I have added a custom health check that uses a repository that hits every 30 seconds so that should keep the data source bean alive but incase it does go down I would need a way to recreate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with test-while-idle=true. That way your idle connections will always be active.

Comment: Not the best idea, but you can poll the database every 5 - 8 hours to keep the connection alive.

Comment: I think the idea here is to keep idle connections alive. Frequency can be minutes or hours depending on the need.

Comment: ideally in a production environment the idle time is no where near 8 hours, but if it were I would need to be able to recreate the bean for the data source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that boot is configuring the DataSource for you. In this case, and since you are using MySQL, you can add the following to your application.properties up to 1.3

```
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

Comment: So i have tried this and still no luck, I believe because I am setting up the bean, because the password is stored in AWS KMS, this doesn't work as if I had all the details specified in the application.property file

Answer (score 0):

Might considered a pooled datasource connector. Look at apache dbcb2.

Here is a sample i have that keeps a minimum of 10 idle and increases as needed from the pool.

```
private static DataSource createDataSource(String url, String userName, String passwrd) throws Exception {
    Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", userName);
    props.setProperty("password", passwrd);

    //Create a connection factory that the pool will use to create connections
    ConnectionFactory cf = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(url, props);
    //Create the poolable connection factory 
    PoolableConnectionFactory pcf = new PoolableConnectionFactory(cf, null);
    pcf.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    pcf.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);

    GenericObjectPoolConfig poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(10);
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(100);

    AbandonedConfig abandonConfig = new AbandonedConfig();
    abandonConfig.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    abandonConfig.setLogAbandoned(false);
    abandonConfig.setRemoveAbandonedOnBorrow(true);
    abandonConfig.setRemoveAbandonedOnMaintenance(true);

    //Create the pool of connections
    GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool<>(pcf, poolConfig);
    connectionPool.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    connectionPool.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    connectionPool.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(10000);
    connectionPool.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(1000);
    connectionPool.setAbandonedConfig(abandonConfig);
    pcf.setPool(connectionPool);

    //Pooling data source itself
    PoolingDataSource<PoolableConnection> dataSource = new PoolingDataSource<>(connectionPool);
    return dataSource;
  }
```

Maven dependencies for apache dbcb2

```
        <!-- Database connection pools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What library is ConnectionFactory in?

Comment: `org.apache.commons.dbcb2` is the package for the apache dbcb2 libraries. i added the maven dependencies to my answer (if you are using maven)